# How to Trigger MS Access Code based on specific time of day rather than every second or minutes

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have been trying to pull this off and maybe I am getting close.
I have some code in Access I need to Run at a specific time of day. I do not want to use Windows Task Scheduler.

***So I have this function:***

```
Public Function RunProgram()
Dim RunDateFormat As String

RunDateFormat = Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS")
    If RunDateFormat = ("15:30:00") Then

'Call these codes and other stuff in here

End If
```

Then I create a Macro called Macro1 to call the function, the form On Timer calls
the Macro as indicated below.

[image]

The problem is if I set the interval to; example: 1000, I get an email every second and the program keeps running.

Please help: I need to set this so the code runs at the exact time but only one time.

Comment: I have to ask. Why don't you want to use Windows Task Scheduler? You can get it to kick off a specific macro that carries out a script and closes Access.  I've used it myself on a virtual machine with few if any problems.

Comment: Agree with @PowerUser, Task Scheduler is not bad at all, especially in comparison to timer events. Timer events are a pig to develop with and cause all sorts of nuisances.

Comment: I tried using Task Scheduler, but for the strangest reason I get an error: ActiveX component can't create object. I posted this on MS Website and even contacted the author of several books and this forum, no one was able to resolved it. I tried for a month and just gave up.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy, I've gotten that cryptic little error quite a few times and could usually fix it by 'fiddling' with the code somehow, but it's been a few years.  I don't think there's a single answer for it.  It may be due to logging out instead of just locking your machine (if you log out, Access can't create objects, I think?).  If you want to go back and explore the task scheduler option instead of coding it all up in Access, just make a new question and we'll see if we can help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you use a static date variable:

```
static dateRan as date
if dateRan = Date then exit Function
If RunDateFormat = ("15:30:00") Then
dateRan = date
'Call these codes and other stuff in here
End If
```

This way you could keep it running overnight and it will work the next day assuming no error occurs to halt operation.

As I'm sure you're aware, doing a scheduled task through Access requires the form to be up and running so you have a fairly large opportunity to fail to run the your time sensitive task. I really do recommend using the task scheduler if it is feasible.

As hinted at by HelloW, I wouldn't go with every second for checking unless it is critical that the code run about the right time. If it is critical, you may want to do some checks and modify the timerinterval programmatically.

Like so:

```
If Hour(Now) < 14 or Hour(Now) >= 16 then
    me.TimerInterval = 3600000
else
    me.TimerInterval = 30000
end if
```

You could narrow it down more, to where you have the checks run more often the closer you get to the time you need to run your time sensitive code.

Comment: Daniel Cook: I was trying something like that but became confused as to calling the sub with the Macro, also if I am setting the time dynamically, what do I enter in the On Timer and Interval values in the form properties? I got an error when running the static variable about Exit Sub not allow in Function.

Comment: Use Exit Function then, my bad. It doesn't really matter what you set the OnTimer to as long as it runs, I would probably set it to 1, or some very low number and then just know that my code will change it according to the criteria I have written.

Comment: Daniel: I used my original code but added the 1000 to the form interval, called the Macro and added the Exit Function to stop if the time is not the same. It is working just like I needed and on schedule. The downside is I have to leave Access and the form open but I can use different function and the same form to run multiple task, thank you and EVERYONE who posted here!!

Answer (score 1):

Do the time checking in the form's timer event procedure.

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    If TimeValue(Now()) >= #15:30:00# Then
        ' run your job, then turn off the timer
        Me.TimerInterval = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

An approached based on the above code should allow you to avoid sending an email each time you do your time check.

If yours is not a single user application, this situation may be more complicated.  If 2 or more users have the form open at 3:30 PM, should they all attempt to run the job?  Can they?  OTOH, if the job is user-specific, that may be what you want.

Comment: HansUp for some strange reason when I try to change the time format, it gets truncated back to the same format:

Comment: When you type that procedure into your form's module, the VB Editor will change that literal time value from `#15:30:00#` to `#3:30:00 PM#`.  Is that what you mean?  If so, it doesn't matter because both are valid representations of the same Date/Time value.

Comment: Not sure what I am doing but the code runs and than at other times doesn't. My confusion remains, what do I put in the time Interval.
Based on your code, the timer interval stops, does it restarts the next day? Since Zero is for off, I put 1000 as Daniel recommended.

Comment: Set your timer interval (eg `Me.TimerInterval = 1000`) in `Form_Load()` so the frequency begins with that value each time you open it.  It will remain at that frequency until 3:30 PM when `Form_Timer()` shuts it off ... sets it to zero.

Comment: thanks, but I am not opening/shutting the form. This is a single application, So I open Access/form and just leave it running until computer breaks. :) I just need the time to fire every time as at the specified time. I do not have any access apps, just this.

Comment: That's another wrinkle I hadn't considered.  In that case you would have to leave the timer running.  Actually, I would abandon the form timer approach and do what you need as a Windows scheduled task.  However, I realize you're opposed to that.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Format(Now(), "HH:MM:00")` to `Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS")`  This will give you the seconds which is what you seem to be looking for.  As a best practice, I don't think it is a good idea to run this every second.  Maybe every minute or quarter hour and test it then.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I want to run the code one time, not every second.