# How to get vba code to run every 3 seconds? (Access)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to write an update script to update missing values.

```
    Function InsertAny()
    MsgBox ("Hello")

    callAgain
End Function

Function callAgain()
    Dim alertTime As String
    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
    Forms("HiddenForm1").OnTime alertTime, "InsertAny"
    'Forms("HiddenForm1").TimerInterval = 3

End Function
```

However I keep getting :

> Run-time error '2465':
>   Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: It is `Application.OnTime` and you better read this : http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx and see another example here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741488/cannot-run-the-macro/33751263#33751263 , because it is not the right way to use `OnTime`

Comment: It says 'method or datamember not found' for `OnTime`

Comment: https://www.google.fr/search?q=ms+access+OnTime&oq=ms+access+OnTime&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.7247j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848608/how-to-trigger-ms-access-code-based-on-specific-time-of-day-rather-than-every-se

Comment: `Application.OnTime` exists in Excel but not in Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case error 2465 appears because you used Form instead of Application. Form expects property: `OnTimer`, not `OnTime`.

**Edit**

As I understand, you need to call `InsertAny` every 3 seconds. In this case just place

```
Call InsertAny()
```

in `OnTimer` event of `HiddenForm1` form and start timer by code

```
Forms("HiddenForm1").TimerInterval = 3
```