# In MS Access is it possible to automatically update data based on date criteria?

Tags: ms-access

For example products have a release date and currently lookup the associated price category A, B or C from a second table - I am looking for a way to automatically change the price category based on the time since release.

Comment: This question can help you sort out what you need

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848608/how-to-trigger-ms-access-code-based-on-specific-time-of-day-rather-than-every-se

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes. Long answer: Use an UPDATE query

```
UPDATE Products
SET CategoryID = 2
WHERE CategoryID = 1 AND ReleaseDate BETWEEN #2015/01/01# AND #2015/12/31#
```

I prefer to use the year first date format, as the position of days and months is always the same.

Since you don't give us much information on your table structures, this is only a guess.

You can also use the Access [`DateDiff`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php) and `Date` functions in order to calculate the time since release automatically.